# node-red displaying msyql results using the dashboard node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node-red

Newbie question: I've started playing with node-red and think it could be a great gateway drug for node.js (and javascript for that matter). But I'm already a bit stuck.

I have a flow which is performing a very simply query against a mysql database. I'm getting the results returned to me, but I have so far not been able to parse those results in any meaningful way. It looks the results are returned as an array, but how can I access and manipulate that array, in a function? Below is the data being passed in from the mysql node:

```
[
  { "at_time": "2017-03-27T18:33:46.000Z", "event": "gone_to_bed" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-27T22:14:02.000Z", "event": "woke_up" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-27T22:14:12.000Z", "event": "food" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-28T00:13:42.000Z", "event": "woke_up" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-28T03:50:15.000Z", "event": "woke_up" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-28T05:12:33.000Z", "event": "woke_up" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-28T05:12:38.000Z", "event": "food" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-28T06:56:29.000Z", "event": "up_for_day" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-28T18:08:49.000Z", "event": "gone_to_bed" },
  { "at_time": "2017-03-28T18:32:48.000Z", "event": "woke_up" }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to format code and code-like things (eg. your JSON snippet) for readability. It will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: That is considerably more readable! Thanks for the edit and I'll do the same in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript arrays have many functions available to help you work with their content. It is too broad a subject to provide a succinct answer without more details on specifically what you want to do.

As you identify, Node-RED is built using JavaScript and its Function node is no different.

Assuming your Function is receiving that array as `msg.payload`, you would use the following syntax to access the various elements:

```
var firstElement = msg.payload[0];
var secondElement = msg.payload[1];
```

and so on.

Each element of that array appears to be a JavaScript object - with key/value pairs. To access those values you would use the following syntax:

```
var first_at_time = firstElement.at_time;
var first_event = firstElement.event;
```

These are fundamental operations with javascript and there are plenty of guides available that will introduce you to them, such as: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays

Comment: Thanks for info - it's much appreciated! When I'm home tonight I will see if I can implement what you have described above. As you can see, I have a few basic concepts to internalize (it was the key/value pairs that had me stumped) but I'm excited by the potential presented by node-red and hope to be less of a newb in the near future.